# Heartbleed bug affecting magento

Tags: security

Are magento sites affected by heartbleed bugs and if yes what can I do for mitigation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heartbleed is server software (OpenSSL) bug so it's more like a server vulnerability.

Here is the link to check if your server is affected: http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

The fix is just to upgrade OpenSSL to the newer version.

You can also mail your Magento customers asking for password change but this will be more of a panic.

Comment: This hopefully goes without saying, but in at least three instances I've encountered folks upgraded OpenSSL and forgot to restart the servers.

Answer (score 1):

Tim is correct, but I think the "panic" is correct.

Heartbleed opened your openSSL memory to the public, this means, everybody was able to read 16kb chunks of your memory. In this memory are stored:

- private keys
- request data
- response data

This means, you have at least to upgrade your openssl version (as Tim said) AND **change your private key**!

Beside of this, attackers might be able to read the password and username, therefore resetting the passwords for all users is a good idea.